# how to send the data to the form and send the form using python requests?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to go to the link, then send the data to the form and then the form itself, through requests this is dealt by only through the parameters that need to be specified in the link, but I can not get the full right link to send the form, that is, I know link, and how it is formed after sending the data I do not know.

if you open the development tools, and go to the network panel, there are indicated in the parameters such lines:

```
Query string
    action Login
    module Users

Form data
    __vtrftk sid: 34b6b3446d78b01ccb1e5678c89c86365a280a51,1521970011
    password you
    username hey
```

And if you go to the Headers and click on the Edit and Resend button: there will be a `"Request Body"` there and there all three fields, csrf, user and pass.

```
__vtrftk=sid%3A34b6b3446d78b01ccb1e5678c89c86365a280a51%2C1521970011&username=hey&password=you
```

how to login through python script using requests?

this is the link for the request http://74.207.247.199:8181/index.php?module=Users&action=Login

this is my poor script

```
import sys
import requests
from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


target = 'http://74.207.247.199:8181/'

sec_target = 'http://74.207.247.199:8181/index.php?module=Users&action=Login'
def main(target, sec_target):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        # start of auth
        s = Session()
        get_csrf_token = s.get(target).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(get_csrf_token, 'lxml')
        find_scrf_token_body = soup.find('div', id='loginDiv')
        find_csrf_token_input = find_scrf_token_body.find('input', {"name":"__vtrftk"}).attrs['value']
        #payload ={'__vtrftk':find_csrf_token_input+'&username=someuser&password=somepass'}
        headers = {
        '__vtrftk': find_csrf_token_input,
        'username': 'someuser',
        'password': 'somepass',
        'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0",
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Referer': 'http://74.207.247.199:8181/',
        }
        # Отправляем данные в POST, в session записываются наши куки
        f = s.post(sec_target, headers=headers)
        g = s.get('http://74.207.247.199:8181/index.php?module=Users&action=Login').text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(g, 'lxml')
        find_alert_body = soup.find('div', id='loginDiv')
        find_alert = find_alert_body.find('div', class_='alert alert-error')
        print(find_alert)
        print(f.url)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(target, sec_target)
```